# Existence of certain subalgebras of $C(X)$

Tags: operator-algebras

Suppose $A$ is a commutative  Banach algebra.Knowing that the Gelfand transform is  not surjective but injective  does it imply that $A$ is not isomorphic to $C(X)$ ?

by $M$ we mean the maximal ideal space.

Comment: Not if $X$ is a finite set.

Comment: in my case X is a closed interval.

Comment: Then yes; for example if $X=[-1,1]$, there is a natural isomorphism between $C(X)$ and the algebra of *even* continuous functions, induced by composition with the map $x\mapsto  2|x|-1 $.

Comment: you mean closure of even functions?

Comment: Even functions form a closed subalgebra of $C([-1,1])$.

Comment: sure. the whole came about the following:suppose Gelfand transform from A to C(M) is injective but not surjective then does it imply that A is not isomorphic to C(M)?

Comment: Then please update your question accordingly.

Comment: You mean $A$ is commutative?